# Mobile Navigation Bar Working Uncorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a responsive nav bar with js, css and html. I have a problem right now, when the screen becomes x size (the size I defined as max-width) there is the pop up of the responsive nav bar. Although, only the last anchor (Loja) appears on that. I want it to be displayed flex and the flex-direction to column. As this prints shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNVSY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9QEZ.jpg

https://jsfiddle.net/tL2vp9k5/1/

````
  <header>
      <nav class="menu">   
        <div>
         <ul class="ulLogo">
          <li title="Logo Carla Ornelas">
          
            <a href="#"><img id="espiral" src="../Logo.png"></a>
            
          </li>
         </ul> 
        </div>
        <div>
        <ul class="ulSecções">
         <li> <a href="../Main page/index.html" title="Home">Home</a> </li>
         <li class="carla"> <a class="carlaOrnelas" href="#" title="Carla Ornelas">Carla Ornelas</a>
         <li><a href="#" title="Cursos">Cursos</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Conteudos Especiais">Conteúdos Especiais</a>  </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Conteudos Especiais">Recursos</a></li>
         <li> <a href="" title="Contatos">Contatos</a> </li>
         <li> <a href="" title="Acesse a nosa loja" class="loja">Loja <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="burger">
          <div class="line1"></div>
          <div class="line2"></div>
          <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
  </header>


/*Universal Commands*/
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration: none;
}


                                             /*Nav bar*/
/*Background Menu*/

nav.menu {

    width:100%;
    height: 85px;
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 3px;
}


/*Costumização do body */

body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
body .menu{
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}

/*Costumização logo */



.ulLogo li  {

    list-style: none;
}


.ulLogo li a img{

    width: 180px;
    float:left;
    padding: 19px 0px 0px 60px;

}
/*Transição Logo Opacity*/
.ulLogo li a img#espiral:hover {

    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity 300ms linear 0s;
}
.ulLogo li a img#espiral:not(:hover) {

    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 399ms linear 0s;
}

/*Costumização sections */
nav .ulSecções {

    float: left;
    padding-left: 90px;
}

nav ul.ulSecções li{ 

    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 90px;
}

nav ul.ulSecções li a{

    
    display:block;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", "Palatino", sans-serif ;
    color:rgb(192, 163, 68);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    opacity: 0.9;

    padding: 0px 18px;
}

nav ul.ulSecções li a i{

    font-size: 16px;

}
nav ul.ulSecções li a.loja{

    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

/* Transition das anchors */

nav ul.ulSecções li a:hover {

    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: color 150ms ease-in 0s,
                opacity 150ms ease-in 0s;

}

nav ul.ulSecções li a:not(:hover) {

    color: rgb(204, 174, 75);
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: color 150ms ease-in 0s,
                opacity 150ms ease-in 0s;

}

/*Mobile screen adjustments*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1250px){
    nav ul.ulSecções li {

    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 14vh;
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    }
}  ```
````

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `<li>` elements have the exact same position, so they're layered on top of eachother. If I remove the background you can clearly see this (see image at the bottom).

you need to select your `<ul>` element, not the `<li>` elements

```css
/* @media screen and (max-width: 1250px){
    nav ul.ulSecções li { */
@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
  nav ul.ulSecções {
```

[image]